# Problems with Pandas_ta library getting CCI key error

Tags: pandas, dataframe, cci

Below is the code for cci.py, for which I am using `pandas_ta`:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_ta as ta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Replace 'your_dataset.csv' with your actual file path
df = pd.read_csv('output-copy.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], dayfirst=True)

# Calculate Commodity Channel Index (CCI)
df.ta.cci(close="Close", length=20, append=True)

# Plot the closing prices and CCI
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(df['Date'], df['Close'], label='Close Price', color='black')
plt.plot(df['Date'], df['CCI_20_2.0'], label='CCI', color='blue')

# Add a horizontal line at +100 and -100 for reference
plt.axhline(100, color='red', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.8, la`your text`bel='CCI +100')
plt.axhline(-100, color='green', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.8, label='CCI -100')

plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Check if CCI is greater than +100 or less than -100
cci_threshold = 100
df['CCI_Signal'] = 0  # Initialize a new column for signals

# Set signals based on CCI threshold
df.ta.sma(length=2)  # Calculate a simple moving average (SMA) for demonstration
df.ta.cci(close="Close", length=20, append=True)  # Recalculate CCI with pandas_ta for signal calculations

df.loc[df['CCI_20_2.0'] > cci_threshold, 'CCI_Signal'] = 1  # Sell Signal
df.loc[df['CCI_20_2.0'] < -cci_threshold, 'CCI_Signal'] = -1  # Buy Signal

# Print the signals
if 1 in df['CCI_Signal'].values:
    print("Potential Sell Signal Detected")
else:
    print("Potential Buy Signal Detected")

# Display the DataFrame with CCI signals
print(df[['Date', 'CCI_20_2.0', 'CCI_Signal']])
```

However, when I run the code, I get the error below:

```
raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'CCI_20_2.0'
```

From my research I am able to understand, I not able to properly write the column name or something similar

What exactly is the error and how do I solve it?`

Comment: Add print(df.columns) right after creating the dataframe. Does the output contain 'CCI_20_2.0'? Most likely not. If it does, on what line the error happens?

Comment: `KeyError: 'CCI_20_2.0'` in pandas  = don have `CCI_20_2.0` column. chk your column like above answer.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi. You could start with isolating the line raising the error yourself, and avoid posting whatever comes later in the code (irrelevant for this post). Even better for [mre], post the output of `print(df.head())`. But in fact it is pretty clear that your first plot is calling a column of the dataframe that does not exist, as Panda Kim pointed out.

Comment: Where exactly? Please update your post with the full error trace (and remove any code that comes after the error) - see how to create a [mre].